# Opennebula KVM onevnet

Tags: kvm-virtualization, bridge, opennebula

I am experimenting with Open Nebula and KVM and so far I have a frontend and a few hosts (all hosts have two NICs for redundancy). 
I know that KVM makes on the hosts a virtual interface virbr0.

Now, to make a VM from opennebula you must define a virtual NIC.
I have to make a template and specify the bridge. Do I specify the virbr0 or something else?
All I want to deploy is that small premade ttylinux available from the [opennebula documentation](http://opennebula.org/documentation:rel3.2:vmg).

I am asking this because I experimented with creating a new bridge myself over the two NICs on  one host and I made a loop and crashed the whole network :)

Answer (score 0):

The right way of doing this is by enabling STP or by bonding the two NICs and creating the bridge on top of the bond (mond you, not all bond modes work with bridging, mode 0 and 6 are definitely not going to work properly)

I am not familiar with opennebula though, so can't help you there.